# WordPress - footer is overlapping my content

Tags: wordpress, templates

I have a problem with editing of wordpress template called - Ribbon. My footer is not at the end of webpage. When I used position: absolute and bottom: 0px for footer, then some longer text overlapping this content. I have made a lot of changes in CSS, but I have no idea, how to make footer always on bottom of my page. I will appreciate every advice, which could help me with this problem. I will add CSS file from template and generated HTML code of page, where I see my problem.

CSS code:

http://pastebin.com/qY7hXUC3

HTML of page:

http://pastebin.com/ByTzP9e7

Thank you

Comment: this might be helpful http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

Answer (score 0):

Replace the following  code for footer and main-container. Footer will remain at the bottom all the time.

```
.main-container{width: 1050px;
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 100%;
padding-bottom: 65px;} 

body>footer{overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
background-color: #FF9900;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;}
```